# Python round does not return integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I wrote the following piece of code to round off the floating values in the dataframe `a`

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1.2,3.4],[1.4,4.6]])
a = a.apply(round)
```

But the output I get is as follows:

```
    0   1
0   1.0 3.0
1   1.0 5.0
```

Why does the function return rounded off floating point values and not an integer?

Also, on being applied as follows, the behaviour is different:

```
round(0.5)
>>0
```

```
x= [1.4,2.5,3.6]
list(map(round,x))

>>[1, 2, 4]
```

Why this anomaly?

Comment: Why not just convert to int? `a.round().astype(int)` Also, what if you have NaNs in column? That column cannot be downcast.

Comment: `round` does return `int` in this case. You are really asking why **pandas** does not change the column's type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apply` calls the `round` function on each column in succession. DataFrame columns are `Series` objects, and [these have a `__round__` dunder method defined on them](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11763) with a slightly different behaviour. This is actually what `round` calls when called on the `Series`.

```
round(a[0])

0    1.0
1    1.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64

# Same as,
a[0].__round__()

0    1.0
1    1.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Contrast this with the typical behaviour for python `round` on scalars:

```
round(1.5)
# 2

 # Same as,
(1.5).__round__()
# 2
```

If you want the same behaviour, use `applymap`.

```
a.applymap(round)

   0  1
0  1  3
1  1  5
```

Which applies `round` on each *element* (scalar), rounding down to an integer.

Or, my recommended solution,

```
a.round().astype(int)

   0  1
0  1  3
1  1  5
```

Beware that this will not typecast columns containing missing data (NaNs).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = a.apply(round).astype(dtype=np.int64)
```

just use this `astype` to convert your `float` to `integer`.